# How to model with "isoline display" in 3DS Max?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max, modeling

When used a "turbosmooth" modifier with "edged faces" pressed on, there is a feature called "Isoline display", which ignores all other edges but those from the original geometry and at the same time they adjusting to the shape of the edges of the turbosmooth modifier. - 
[image]

However, when work in "Editable poly" with the modifier displaied at the same time, those edges are still there, however I can work only with the straight edges (the orange once), not with those that are made by the "Isoline display" - 
[image]

Is there a way to work with those edges? It would look something like this - 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is still not possible in 3dsmax.

5 years ago I talked about this being the case, and it is still not there and not planned to be in 3dsmax 2016.

Comment: It is kinda weird that they're not adding that feature 'cause it would really assist in topology among other stuff. Thanks for the answer :)